# How to deselect a radio button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have looked at several online tutorials, none of them seem to work properly, I need to have the radio button deselected once the clear button is clicked. The .deselect() method does nothing. Clearing the text and entry boxes is working properly. Please assist.

Thank you,

```
from tkinter import *



class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("TCPDUMP Creator")
        #self.centerWindow()
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=5)

        lf = LabelFrame(parent, text="Filter Data")
        lf.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
        f = LabelFrame(lf, width=600, height=300)
        frame1 = LabelFrame(lf, text="Interface")


        frame1.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        #frame1.place(relx=0.10, rely=0.125, anchor=NW)
        int_lbl = Label(frame1, text="Int.")
        int_lbl.pack(side="left", fill=X)
        self.int_entry = Entry(frame1, width=15)
        self.int_entry.pack(side="left")

        frame2 = Label(lf, text="")
        frame2.pack(side='top', fill=X)

        self.anyInt = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(frame1, text="Any", variable = self.anyInt).pack(side="left")

        frame2=LabelFrame(lf, text="IP Options")
        frame2.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.notSrc = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(frame2, text = "Not--", variable = self.notSrc).pack(side="left")
        self.srcIP = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(frame2, text="Src", variable = self.srcIP).pack(side="left")
        self.src_entry = Entry(frame2, width=15)
        self.src_entry.pack(side="left")

        self.AndOr = StringVar()
        self.AndOr.set(None)

        andbtn = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "And", variable = self.AndOr, value = "And").pack(side="left", padx=25)
        orbtn = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Or", variable = self.AndOr, value = "Or").pack(side="left", padx=15)

        self.notDst = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(frame2, text = "Not--", variable = self.notDst).pack(side="left", padx=20)

        self.dstIP = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(frame2, text="Dst", variable = self.dstIP).pack(side="left")

        self.dst_entry = Entry(frame2, width=15)
        self.dst_entry.pack(side="left")

        frame3 = Label(lf, text="")
        frame3.pack(side='top', fill=X)

        frame3 = LabelFrame(lf, text="")
        frame3.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        self.AndOrport = StringVar()
        self.AndOrport.set(None)

        srcAnd=Radiobutton(frame3, text = "And", variable = self.AndOrport, value = "And").pack(side='left')
        self.srcOr=Radiobutton(frame3, text = "Or", variable = self.AndOrport, value = "Or").pack(side='left')

        frame4 = Label(lf, text="")
        frame4.pack(side='top', fill=X)

        frame4 = LabelFrame(lf, text="Ports")
        frame4.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        self.notSrcPort = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(frame4, text = "Not--", variable = self.notSrcPort).pack(side="left")

        self.srcport_lbl = Label(frame4, text="Src Port")
        self.srcport_lbl.pack(side="left")

        self.srcport_entry = Entry(frame4, width=15)
        self.srcport_entry.pack(side="left")

        self.SrcDstport = StringVar()
        self.SrcDstport.set(None)

        Radiobutton(frame4, text = "And", variable = self.SrcDstport, value = "And").pack(side='left', padx=25)
        Radiobutton(frame4, text = "Or", variable = self.SrcDstport, value = "Or").pack(side='left', padx=15)

        self.notDstPort = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(frame4, text = "Not--", variable = self.notDstPort).pack(side="left")

        self.dstport_lbl = Label(frame4, text="Dst Port")
        self.dstport_lbl.pack(side="left")

        self.dstport_entry = Entry(frame4, width=15)
        self.dstport_entry.pack(side="left")

        frame5 = Label(lf, text="")
        frame5.pack(side="top", fill=X)

        frame5 = LabelFrame(lf, text="Options")
        frame5.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        self.listInterfaces = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(frame5, text = "List Interfaces", variable = self.listInterfaces).pack(side="left")

        cap_lbl = Label(frame5, text="# of Packets to Capture")
        cap_lbl.pack(side="left")
        self.cap_entry = Entry(frame5, width=3)
        self.cap_entry.pack(side="left")

        self.noDNS = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(frame5, text = "Don't Translate Hostnames & Ports", variable = self.noDNS).pack(side="left", padx=15)

        verbosity_lbl = Label(frame5, text="Verbosity:")
        verbosity_lbl.pack(side="left")

        self.verbosity = StringVar()
        self.verbosity.set(None)

        Radiobutton(frame5, text = "Low", variable = self.verbosity, value = "-v").pack(side='left')
        Radiobutton(frame5, text = "Med", variable = self.verbosity, value = "-vv").pack(side='left', padx=15)
        Radiobutton(frame5, text = "High", variable = self.verbosity, value = "-vvv").pack(side='left', padx=15)

        frame6 = LabelFrame(lf, text="")
        frame6.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        self.timeformat = StringVar()
        self.timeformat.set(None)

        Radiobutton(frame6, text="Human Readable Time Format", variable=self.timeformat, value="-tttt").pack(side="left", padx=10)
        self.write2file = StringVar()
        self.write2file.set(None)
        Radiobutton(frame6, text = "Write to File", variable = self.write2file, value="-w").pack(side='left')
        write_lbl = Label(frame6, text="Filename")
        write_lbl.pack(side="left")
        self.file_entry = Entry(frame6, width=15)
        self.file_entry.pack(side='left')

        frame7 = Label(lf, text="")
        frame7.pack(side='top', fill=X)

        frame8 = Label(lf, text="")
        frame8.pack(side="top", fill=X)

        createBttn = Button(frame8, text="Create", width=15, height=2, relief="ridge", anchor=CENTER, command=self.create)
        createBttn.pack(side="left", padx=70)

        clearBttn = Button(frame8, text="Clear", width=15, height=2, relief="ridge", anchor=CENTER, command=self.clear)
        clearBttn.pack(side="left", padx=70)

        self.exitBttn = Button(frame8, text="Exit", width=15, height=2, relief="ridge", anchor=CENTER, command=self.exit)
        self.exitBttn.pack(side="left", padx=70)

        frame9 = Label(lf, text="Filter Data")
        frame9.pack(side="top", fill=X)

        frame10 = Label(lf, text="")
        frame10.pack(side="left")

        self.filterData = Text(frame10, width=95, height=1.2)
        self.filterData.pack(side="left")


    def centerWindow(self):
        w = 600
        h = 300
        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2.7
        self.parent.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))

    def clear(self):
        try:
            self.filterData.delete(0.0, END)    #delete from text box
            self.int_entry.delete(0, END)       #delete from entry box
            self.src_entry.delete(0, END)
            self.dst_entry.delete(0, END)
            self.srcport_entry.delete(0, END)
            self.dstport_entry.delete(0, END)
            self.file_entry.delete(0, END)
            self.cap_entry.delete(0, END)
            self.anyInt.set(0)
            self.notSrc.set(0)
            self.srcIP.set(0)
            self.noDNS.set(0)
            self.listInterfaces.set(0)
            self.notDstPort.set(0)
            self.notSrcPort.set(0)
            self.dstIP.set(0)
            self.srcAnd.deselect()
            self.srcOr.deselect()
            self.SrcDstport.deselect()
            deselect(self.timeformat)
            self.write2file.deselect()
            self.SrcDstport.deselect()


        except:
            pass
    def exit(self):
        self.quit()

    def create(self):
        if self.anyInt.get():
            self.filterData.insert(0.0, "tcpdump " + "-i " + "any")
        else:
            self.filterData.insert(0.0, "tcpdump " + "-i " + self.int_entry.get())





def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you checked the doc? And please only include codes that's concise enough to only show the problem area and still keep it reproducible

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum amount needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @abccd: What documentation?

Comment: From a usability perspective, you should always have one selected. If none are viable defaults, I recommend adding another like "no answer" or "none of the above".

Comment: Let me guess....maybe the [tk doc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/radiobutton.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
self.SrcDstport.deselect()
```

You are trying to deselect the StringVar. You need to set it to something that isn't an option, in other words a value that none of the Radiobuttons use in the value argument:

```
self.SrcDstport.set(None)
```

Comment: Of course! That makes sense, really appreciate your help!