# Disable rariobuttons

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have 3 radio buttons in an app. when i press the OK button things happen based on what was selected.  Now I would like to clear the radio button that was selected prior to returning to the main loop of the app.

```
rbtVar = IntVar()
rbtVar.set(1)
btnOptions = ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"]
for x in range(len(btnOptions)):
    Radiobutton(rgtFrame, text=btnOptions[x], variable=rbtVar, value=x+1).grid(column=1, row=x+1, sticky = W)

btnOK = ttk.Button(rgtFrame, text="OK", command=cmdOK)
```

In a perfect world when I return from cmdOK none of the radio buttons will be selected.

TIA!

Comment: I think that `.set(None)` - as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43403694/4092588) - can be what you are searching for

Comment: Thanks Antonio that did the trick.

Comment: AntoniNo :) no worries, my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

From a usability point of view, that's not how radiobuttons are designed to work. There should always be one that is set.

If you insist on having them appear unselected, just create a forth item for "unselected" and then don't show that option to the user.